# PFQueryTableViewController "No Results" Cell

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

I am using a PFQueryTableViewController to display data from PFObjects but I want to create an alternative cell for when there are no objects to show. I tried doing this but when I return 1 in numberOfRowsInSection, I get the following error: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

I'm not sure what to do but here's the code that I have:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.objects count] != 0){
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [self.objects count];
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your cellForIndexPath function. I predict that's your problem.

Comment: I already have cellForRowAtIndexPath. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What's it look like. I suspect it's wrong.

Comment: Okay. When I run it with a breakpoint at cellForRowAtIndexPath, the breakpoint doesn't even get triggered before it crashes.

Comment: Would you drop by [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61287/parse-com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the answer to this question: https://www.parse.com/questions/adding-static-cells-to-the-beginning-of-a-pfquerytableviewcontroller